# Tuning Tomcat connector

Tags: tomcat

I have a Java web service that does some resource-intensive data processing. I'm trying to adjust such Tomcat connector properties as `maxThreads`, `maxConnections` and `acceptCount` in order to prevent the service from overload.
I created also a test client that simulates production load of the service.
For several minutes after starting the client I see Tomcat behaving in the expected way. Below is a typical CPU load histogram in this period.
[image: Initial CPU load]

Then I see the response times to increase and in a short while the number of refused connections reaches 100%.
What surprises me is the CPU load being far from 100% and its character of "thready pulse".

[image: CPU thready pulse]

The current connector settings are below.

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="4000" redirectPort="8443"
           minSpareThreads="8" maxThreads="12" maxConnections="24" acceptCount="8" />
```

Could anybody please suggest the appropriate values for my case?

Comment: The connector configuration you have shown is highly dependent on other factors. What version of Tomcat? Are you using `tcnative`? You can see by checking your `logs/catalina.out` file when Tomcat starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that some specific requests take extremely long time to process (several minutes).
I found out (thanks to the great tool VisualVM) that with the reduced number of threads all of them get at some point occupied with those long-running requests. Therefore Tomcat rejects all new requests despite the available CPU capacity.
After taking some precautions against those long-running requests the service works in the desired way.

Answer (score 1):

> Could anybody please suggest the appropriate values for my case?

Finding "appropriate" values is not straightforward. And to understand why refused connections reaches 100% you need to see what those `maxConnections="24"` are doing.

Finding above is as simple as sending `kill -3 <tomcat_pid>` and observing thread dump output of `catalina.out`. Perhaps the lacking resource might not be CPU but some other, e.g. database, badly implemented locking, or another problem problem which you haven't even thought about.